# PR_SPAM_TRUSTED_SENDERS_W and PR_SPAM_BLOCKED_SENDERS

Tags: vba, outlook

I've played quite a bit with "PR_SPAM_BLOCKED_SENDERS" ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6106001F") and using VBA to manipulate/update my Spam list in real time in OL (o365), and it works just great.
I long forgot how and where I got hold of the proptag for it, but I did somehow, and now I need to get hold of the safe list (PR_SPAM_TRUSTED_SENDERS_W) as well, but the only proptag ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x001f0418") I've found so far fails:-(

Can you help me out here - what is the correct proptag?

Here is some base code that work great for the blocked (PR_SPAM_BLOCKED_SENDERS), but not the safe (PR_SPAM_TRUSTED_SENDERS_W):

```
  Const PR_SPAM_TRUSTED_SENDERS_W = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x001f0418"
  Const PR_SPAM_BLOCKED_SENDERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6106001F"

  Set oStorage = oInbox.GetStorage("Junk E-mail Rule", olIdentifyBySubject)
  Set oPropAcc = oStorage.propertyAccessor
  sBlockedSenders = oPropAcc.GetProperty(PR_SPAM_BLOCKED_SENDERS)
  Debug.Print sBlockedSenders
```

Many thanks in advance!

Best Regards,

Bjarne Dein

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored inside the `PR_EXTENDED_RULE_CONDITION` binary property - take a look at the rule with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - go to the Inbox folder, click IMAPIFolder button, find the rule hidden message on the "Associated Contents" tab, open the message. Select the PR_EXTENDED_RULE_CONDITION property - OutlookSpy will parse it and display its data. You can also take a look at the IMAPIFolder | PR_RULES_TABLE tab.

You can either parse that property, or use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) - it exposes the [RDOJunkEmailOptions](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdojunkemailoptions.htm) object:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set JunkOptions = Session.JunkEmailOptions
for each vAddress in JunkOptions.TrustedSenders
  Debug.Print vAddress
next
```

In case of an Exchange mailbox, here is how the rule looks like:

```
rt : RES_AND
  cRes : 2
  lpRes : 
    rt : RES_OR
      cRes : 2
      lpRes : 
        rt : RES_OR
          cRes : 1
          lpRes : 
            rt : RES_CONTENT
            resContent : 
              ulFuzzyLevel : FL_FULLSTRING FL_IGNORECASE
              ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
              lpProp :
                ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                Value : blocked.sender@demo.com
    
        rt : RES_AND
          cRes : 2
          lpRes : 
            rt : RES_OR
              cRes : 2
              lpRes : 
                rt : RES_AND
                  cRes : 2
                  lpRes : 
                    rt : RES_EXIST
                    res.resExist :
                      ulPropTag : PR_CONTENT_FILTER_SCL (0x40760003)
                
                    rt : RES_PROPERTY
                    res.resProperty :
                      relop : RELOP_GT
                      ulPropTag : PR_CONTENT_FILTER_SCL (0x40760003)
                      lpProp :
                        ulPropTag : PR_CONTENT_FILTER_SCL (0x40760003)
                        Value : -1
                
                rt : RES_OR
                  cRes : 0
                  lpRes : 
            
            rt : RES_NOT
            res.resNot :
              lpRes : 
                rt : RES_OR
                  cRes : 2
                  lpRes : 
                    rt : RES_OR
                      cRes : 1
                      lpRes : 
                        rt : RES_CONTENT
                        resContent : 
                          ulFuzzyLevel : FL_SUBSTRING FL_IGNORECASE
                          ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                          lpProp :
                            ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                            Value : @safe.sender.domain.com
                    
                    rt : RES_SUBRESTRICTION
                    resSub : 
                      ulSubObject : PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS
                      lpRes :     rt : RES_OR
                          cRes : 0
                          lpRes : 

    rt : RES_NOT
    res.resNot :
      lpRes : 
        rt : RES_OR
          cRes : 3
          lpRes : 
            rt : RES_OR
              cRes : 5
              lpRes : 
                rt : RES_CONTENT
                resContent : 
                  ulFuzzyLevel : FL_FULLSTRING FL_IGNORECASE
                  ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                  lpProp :
                    ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                    Value : safe.sender.1@demo.com
            
                rt : RES_CONTENT
                resContent : 
                  ulFuzzyLevel : FL_FULLSTRING FL_IGNORECASE
                  ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                  lpProp :
                    ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                    Value : safe.sender.2@demo.com
            
                rt : RES_CONTENT
                resContent : 
                  ulFuzzyLevel : FL_FULLSTRING FL_IGNORECASE
                  ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                  lpProp :
                    ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                    Value : safe.sender.3@demo.com
            
                rt : RES_CONTENT
                resContent : 
                  ulFuzzyLevel : FL_FULLSTRING FL_IGNORECASE
                  ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                  lpProp :
                    ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                    Value : safe.sender.4@demo.com
            
                rt : RES_CONTENT
                resContent : 
                  ulFuzzyLevel : FL_FULLSTRING FL_IGNORECASE
                  ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                  lpProp :
                    ulPropTag : PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (0x0C1F001F)
                    Value : safe.sender.5@demo.com
            
            rt : RES_SUBRESTRICTION
            resSub : 
              ulSubObject : PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS
              lpRes :     rt : RES_OR
                  cRes : 0
                  lpRes : 
            
            rt : RES_OR
              cRes : 0
              lpRes :
```

Comment: Have checked via OutlookSpy, and `PR_EXTENDED_RULE_CONDITION` is not there, here is part of the list, and please bare in mind this is OL365:

`PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC PT_STRING8 Junk E-mail Rule

PR_CREATION_TIME PT_SYSTIME 07:10, 17-09-2018
PR_DEPTH PT_LONG 0  
PR_DISPLAY_NAME PT_STRING8 MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND  
PR_DOTSTUFF_STATE PT_LONG MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND  
PR_ENTRYID PT_BINARY cb:24, lpb: EF 00 00 00 41 71 66 A6 6D E1 E8 47 85 FD 29 4E 17 46 55 7C 28 31 10 00  
PR_HASATTACH PT_BOOLEAN false  
PR_ICON_INDEX PT_LONG MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: What about the proptag for Safe Senders, can anyone provide the correct one?

Comment: Is that an Exchange or a PST store? Does the script above work in OutlookSpy (click Script, past the script, click Run)?

Comment: It’s an Exchange (in the cloud) store. The “script” is pure vba code from within OL

Comment: I meant the test script in my reply.

Comment: Keep in mind that the data can be stored in both the Exchange rule and in a profile section (registry).

Comment: I don't see any scripts from you in your reply - where did you put it?
I'm fully aware it can be both places, but I don't find it anywhere using OutlookSpy.
Do you not know of these proptags/schemas?

Comment: The script is in my reply - it creates an instance of the Redemption.RDOSession object and logs the trusted senders:

    set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
    set JunkOptions = Session.JunkEmailOptions
    for each vAddress in JunkOptions.TrustedSenders
      Debug.Print vAddress
    next

Comment: I get this error:
`OutlookSpy Script Error
X
Error executing script: DISP_E_EXCEPTION
Microsoft VBScript runtime error
ActiveX component can't create object:
Redemption.RDOSession'
Line 1, Column 1
OK`
I don't have "Redemption" installed.

Comment: Yes, you need to download and install Redemption from http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/download.htm

Comment: As I expected this worked just perfect, but is not what I needed, as I need to avoid any add-in's, and make it work as it already does with the Blocked Senders just using proptags/schemas.

Comment: Dmitry can you (or who can) provide that schema?
Can Redemption provide this kind of information?

Comment: The data is stored in a profile section, and it is only accessible with Extended MAPI (or Redemption).

Comment: Why and how can I get Blocked Senders then? Aren’t they coming from same Store?

Comment: Again, for an Exchange mailbox, the data is in the rule itself (see the updated answer above). For all other stores, the data is in the profile section stored in the registry.